# The App Store only opens "Updates" — How to fix?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have an iPad running iOS 9.3.5. When I open the App Store it opens with a blank screen, and “Updates” is the only panel that shows any data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If my Answer resolved your problem I would appreciate if you could Accept it (click the checkmark next to it) 

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Double-click the **Home** button (press it twice quickly):
   [image: Home Button]
2. The **Multitasking Screen** appears. Locate the **App Store** and drag it off the screen by swiping up on it:
   [image]
3. Press the **Home** button again.
4. Relaunch the **App Store**.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "home button".  Even so, swiping up on App Store doesn't activate the app store app.  When I open the App Store there is a blank white screen with options at the bottom ("Featured", etc), but the only option that works in "Updates".  How can I get the other options to work?  Thanks.

Comment: I’ve added a photo of the **Home** button and a screenshot of the **Multitasking Screen**. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I thing the multitasking feature only works with Ipad air, mini and pro.  I have neither of these.

Comment: No, it exists in this form on all devices that support iOS 7 or newer, going back to iPad 2.

Comment: Ok, now I understand - It worked:::: Thanks so much for your effort and patience...